# How to Convert weeks into days in Twig/Timber Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber, twig-filter

I have a situation where I have a variable that is set to a number of weeks and I need to convert these weeks to total number of days, but can't seem to get things working: [twigfiddle.com](https://twigfiddle.com/6lwqbp)

Thanks, in advance!

```
{% set totalweeks = 7 Weeks %}

{% set totaldays = totalweeks | (days) %}

Output: {{totaldays}}
```

Comment: Can't you just multiply it for 7? totaldays = totalweeks * 7

Comment: @Agnohendrix I can do that [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/i4NYGbYt) but it throws me a nasty error, something about: `"A non well formed numeric value encountered in ..."` here is an image of the complete error: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/SlmqG0Q) thanks for any help in getting this formatted properly!

Comment: Make sure both values are integers or convert accordingly

Comment: What is the result if you do dump(totalweeks)? And are you doing `{% set totalweeks = 7 Weeks %}` or are you doing `{% set totalweeks = 7 %}` ?

Comment: @Phil how would I convert? And yes Agnohendrix its set to 7 Weeks not 7 (ie, the `7 Weeks` is coming from an acf field - I guess I could rewrite if I need to?)

Comment: Then i guess that is why you can't multiply it, it's probably a string

Comment: How would I convert it?

Comment: I remembered there is a way to get the first character and all I needed for the calculation was the 7 so I just used the first filter in twig: `{% set totaldays = totalweeks | first * 7 %}` and got it working. It still would be nice to know how to covert weeks to days in that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, assuming your variable is a string which value is `"7 Weeks":

```
{% set totalweeks = '7 Weeks' %}

{% set totaldays = totalweeks|trim(' Weeks') * 7 %}

Output: {{totaldays}}

//49
```